# What curve is represented by combining individual curves?

Tags: analytic-geometry

If equations of two curves in a plane are given as

$$ f(x,y)=0,\, g(x,y)=0,\, $$

what geometric interpretation can be given to the following five derived curves  i.e., when seen plotted together in relation to individual $f,g?$

$$ f(x,y - g(x,y)=0,\, \tag1 $$

Particularly if $f,g$ are circles the above represents their radical axis. Next,

$$ f(x,y) +  g(x,y)=0,\, \tag2$$

and with parameter $\lambda$

$$ f(x,y)+ \lambda \, g(x,y)=0,\, \tag3$$

$$ f(x,y) \cdot g(x,y)=1,\, \tag4$$

$$\frac{ 2 f(x,y)\cdot g(x,y) } {f(x,y) + g(x,y)}=1. \tag5$$

Comment: Did you mean the curves are $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ or $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, thanks much for the suggestion,would be changing it.

Comment: Your comment about the radical axis is not true in general. For example, there are many ways to construct a function $f$ such that $f(x,y)=0$ is the equation of the unit circle; only one of these many functions is a quadratic in $x$ and $y.$ Did you forget to mention some restriction on what kind of functions $f$ and $g$ can be?

Comment: I don't think you understood the previous comment. A more concrete example: Let $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2-1,$ $g(x,y) = ((x-1)^2 + y^2)^2-1.$ Now what does $f(x,y)-g(x,y)=0$ describe?

Comment: @DavidK a circle with a bite... :D

Comment: @DavidK  Whatever may be parametric definition ( e.g., hyperbolic) , a circle in the plane remains the same.  My comment before typo correction  equn (1) is that $ x^2+y^2 + ax+by+c  -(x^2+y^2 +Ax+By+C)= 0 $ represents a radical axis in all 3 cases of intersection.

Comment: So you are assuming that $f$ and $g$ will always be quadratic functions of $x$ and $y.$ That is one unstated assumption. You are also making some additional assumptions, for example even though $g_1(x,y)=x^2+y^2+3x+4y+20=0$ and $g_2(x,y)=2x^2+2y^2+6x+8y+40=0$ are equations of the same circle, you will always use $g_1$ and never $g_2,$ because while $x^2+y^2-10-g_1(x,y)=0$ is a line, $x^2+y^2-10-g_2(x,y)=0$ is a circle. But in other cases, how do you decide which formula is correct to use? For example, $x^2+\frac12y^2-1=0$ versus $2x^2+y^2-2=0.$

Comment: I am not making any assumptions about $f,g$ except they are smooth differentiable and so on. In the second example you need to divide by 2 and subtract to get to radical axis. Else you get another circle sharing same fixed points of intersection.

Comment: Smooth differentiable is a big assumption. "And so on" could be a lot more assumptions. And if you're willing to multiply the function by whatever constant is needed in order to make the answer come out to what you want, then it is pointless to distinguish $f(x,y)-g(x,y)$ or $f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)$ from $f(x,y)+g(x,y).$